# EU spouse traveling to Ireland, having Swedish residency and Russian passport

Tags: visas, ireland, residency, russian-citizens, spouses

If Russian citizen, has a EU spouse (traveling together) and Swedish permanent residency.
Does he/she still required a visa to Ireland?

> **Family member of EU national**: If you are a non-EEA national coming to
>   Ireland from another EU country as a dependant of an EU national, and
>   you do not hold a document called "Residence card of a family member
>   of a Union citizen", you may need a visa when you first travel to
>   Ireland.

how to get this ***Residence card of a family member of a Union citizen*** ?

"**you may need a visa**"... may not?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residence_card_of_a_family_member_of_a_Union_citizen

> **Implementation in Ireland**
>
> Ireland calls its Residence Card Stamp 4EUFam (EU Directive
>   2004/38/EC). Ireland has now implemented this part of the directive in
>   full according with the Immigration Act 2004 (Visas) Order 2011 and
>   consequently it is now possible for family members to gain entry into
>   Ireland with a residence card issued by any member state.[6]

Comment: Is the EU spouse a Swedish citizen?

Comment: How did you obtain permanent residency? Were you already a permanent resident before you married?

Comment: Yes, EU spouse is a Swedish citizen. In Sweden I got it because of "family reunion" with my wife, before I had another EU residency.

Comment: What do you mean by another EU residency? You lived in another EU country? Was it with your wife? What was your status then?

Comment: Yes, we lived in another EU country, I had a temporary residency because of my work. Yes, we were married. I just didn't apply for Swedish one, as we didn't live in Sweden that time :) Does it help to answer my question?)

Comment: Yes. The reason I asked is that it might have provided a way for you to get another residence card in Sweden. But if you had a residence permit through your work (as opposed as through your spouse), then it would not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spouse of an EU national can get such a residence card by applying for it in the couple's country of residence (but only if they do *not* reside in the EU citizen's country of citizenship). Most people in this situation would have one anyway because it's typically the easiest solution.

[The relevant Swedish government website has some information about it.](http://www.migrationsverket.se/English/Private-individuals/EU-citizens-and-long-term-residents/Work-study-or-live-in-Sweden-for-EU-citizens/Residence-cards-for-family-who-are-non-EU-citizens.html)

Comment: I have this residency card (got it because of family reunion with my wife). But I guess it's different from "Residence card of a family member of a Union citizen" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residence_card_of_a_family_member_of_a_Union_citizen, as "The residence card should clearly state that the holder is a family member of an EU national." and my card doesn't say anything about it...

Comment: @ViacheslavBakshaev your card doesn't say anything about it because your wife is Swedish. Your residence is therefore not governed by EU law, but by Swedish law.

Comment: @ViacheslavBakshaev Yes, that's why I added “(but only if they do *not* reside in the EU citizen's country of citizenship)”. You do not have this residence card but a regular Swedish residence permit. Your situation is different and you do not qualify for the visa exemption (but you do qualify for a simplified visa, the EEA family permit).

Comment: thx, guys... need to apply then.. :(